# First post audit failed

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

[I just failed an audit in first posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27589852)

This one seems very misleading and counter-intuitive.  During the audit, you can only see the question, but not any answers, the username of the poster, or any votes.   After looking over it, this didn't seem like a good question so I decided to down-vote it.   According to the audit, this was the wrong approach.

I'm not upset by this, as after the audit when I went and was able to actually look at the answer associated it is a good resource, however, I feel like the audit is misleading.  I don't think we should have to navigate away from the review page in order to determine if the question is good or not.

I was also suspended from reviewing this audit as well.

Comment: You can right click on the question title and open it in a new tab/window.

Comment: I understand but that kind of defeats the purpose of the audit IMO and as I stated "I don't think we should have to navigate away from the review page in order to determine if the question is good or not."

Comment: I saw another audit on this question brought up earlier on Meta and was quite skeptical about it too. It does not look like a good candidate at all. I am quite tempted to VTC as too broad, even though the answer is unquestionably useful.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that, as-is, that's a pretty mediocre "question" in of itself; a downvote doesn't seem out of place honestly. The fact that you can fail an audit for downvoting, an action that's largely subjective, is pretty bad design to begin with imo.

Comment: @JeanneDark But that's waaay too much work imo. It would be soo much simpler if one could just see all the answers and comments (not the votes) when reviewing an audit.

Comment: Yeah, these "reference" canonical Q&A are not all that great. I understand the motivation, and I think they are well meant (and I confess to have used them as dupe targets a couple of times), but I think they are not really great questions. They should probably be split up in several more canonicals, if anything.

Comment: *I went and was able to actually look at the answer associated it is a good resource...I don't think we should have to navigate away from the review page in order to determine if the question is good or not.* I'd argue that the answer being good/useful doesn't make the question itself good. I agree with yivi that this question ought to be several given the length of the OP's answer.

Comment: You rarely get suspended over a single failed audit. Irrespective of this audit's suitability, it may be a good idea to take a break anyway.

Comment: Note that since the linked question has multiple downvotes now it no longer will be in "known good" audits. (Not trying to say you how to vote, but -4 usually means it really better be deleted from the site as almost actively harmful)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree, it probably is a good idea to go ahead and take a break.  Original point of this post was to simply bring this questionable audit to the mods attention and get some kind of clarification.   Just noticed the suspension after the fact.

Comment: "kind of defeats the purpose of the audit". ermmm no. Checking for duplicates, checking out the post on the side, searching the internet for plagiarism is just good and thorough reviewing :)

Comment: @Scratte I kind of agree, but at the same time, audits need to be somewhat obvious. One thing would be to perhaps display the comments and answers, because when reviewing, context is pretty important.

Comment: @10Rep I think that would be confusing. Real posts are not obvious, so why should audits be? All audits are in fact also real posts :) ..well except for suggested edits.

Comment: @Scratte Per this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work  It is stated that "The main purpose of audits is to catch robo-reviewers, who mindlessly review without even looking at the posts, and to help educate new reviewers. Easy-to-identify audits help legitimate reviewers pass and help better hone new reviewers' skills." So it seems that it should be easily identifiable.

Comment: Yes, I see. I think that is meant to be declaration of intention, rather than the actual practice. Audits are just real posts that were either very well received, so the system assumes that it's obvious. Or spam, that was removed. Again the system just assumes that it's obvious. It's not obvious in many cases. Spam can get removed because someone posted the same thing in 5 posts and only viewing all of them will give that knowledge. The other issue is that often it takes an expert in that technology to recognize a good post.

Comment: This could be a tricky audit if you're not familiar with the concept of canonical duplicates. But now when you know what they are, you shouldn't fall for this again.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Please don't feel as if I'm trying to drag your question down, I just feel as though canonical questions such as this probably shouldn't be audits.   Don't know if it would even be possible for the system to differentiate one such as this from any other question though.

Comment: It's ok, I don't feel that way. I'm just a bit salty because the question got around 5 downvotes due to the meta effect, with no suggestions on how it could be improved whatsoever.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat not downvoting, but maybe you could include in the question a list of the FAQs you’re answering?

Comment: @JeanneDark or you can middle click the link.

Answer (score -1):

This is intended as a canonical question.

The question is quite broad as written, but I think that this actually makes sense for a canonical Q&A - if the question was too narrow it might be harder to cover all of the "cases" in the answers, which would diminish its usefulness as a dupe target.

I'm not familiar with the subject matter of that particular Q&A, but if a high-rep user claims to be repeatedly answering the same (or very similar) question I'm inclined to believe them. In this case, a canonical Q&A is helpful to the site because it provides a good dupe target so that people don't have to keep answering the same question over and over again.

Comment: Nah. Canonical questions have to be as good as all other questions, and high-rep users don't get a free pass to write crap questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not about high rep. I'd argue that canonical questions should (and do) get a free pass. Consider [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2752075), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/2752075), etc.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I never suggested that we give high-rep users a free pass - that would be moderating users rather than content. I'm suggesting that the fact that they have high rep and presumably answer lots of questions supports their claim that a canonical Q&A is needed.

Comment: That's good then, @EJoshuaS. I just wanted to make sure that everyone knew that high-rep is not sufficient protection for questions getting closed. At least for my vote to close. Apparently others feel differently.